# Trying to get Python code in flask to use input from html form

Tags: python, flask, input

This is the flask code snippet I am trying to get to work. I get an error that response variable is not associated with anything. When I try the Python code on its own in my terminal, it works fine.

```
@app.route('/weather', methods=["GET","POST"])
def weather():

    API_KEY = "SOME KEY I GOT"
    BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"

    if request.method == "POST":
        city = request.form.get["city"]

        request_url = f"{BASE_URL}?appid={API_KEY}&q={city}"
        response = requests.get(request_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        weather = data['weather'][0]['description']
        temperature = round(data["main"]["temp"] - 273.15, 2)

        return render_template("weather.html")
    else:
# return("/index")
```

I want to have users input the city name in the form on my html page and use this input to pass it on the python code. I tried using GET instead of POST... didn't work. Flask doesn't even want to show the html file, it says internal server error. What I am missing?

Comment: If there was a `GET` request, what would you expect response to be? It would be an undefined variable...

Comment: The code starting with `if response.status_code == 200` needs to be indented at the same level as `response = requests.get(request_url)`

Comment: Try looking at [How to use Web Forms in a Flask Application](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-web-forms-in-a-flask-application).

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Turns out square brackets for city were wrong. Need parenthesis!